# VS code shortcut to toggle from code window to terminal in Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, ctrl

What is the keyboard shortcut on VSCODE in MacBook to toggle between terminal and file or to say to open the VS CODE terminal?

In windows, the same works when `CTRL` + `~` is pressed but the same isn't the case on Mac. I tried with command and option key too.

Answer (score 3):

CTRL + ` should perform this same behavior on Mac, else you can also try COMMAND + J, which should result in the same behavior of folding/unfolding the terminal.